# the usage of word lack

Tags: vocabulary

I saw an example sentence of the usage of word "lack" and it triggered another question in my mind.

The sentence is that

> The teacher was **lacking in** communication skill

but what if I say

> The teacher was **lacking** communication skill

Because dictionaries say that word is used like "<someone> lacks <something>"

So my questions are:

1. Is my sentence grammatically correct?
2. Does my sentence have the same meaning?
3. When should I use the form "lack in"?

Answer (score 2):

Colloquially, the plural is used for *skill* in this context:

*The teacher was lacking in communication skills.*

Stylistically the second sentence is not bad, but I would use the simpler:

*The teacher lacked communication skills.*

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student. Do you think is there any difference in terms of meaning in the sentences?

Comment: Only a very small difference...without the **in** implies a deficiency across all areas of communication skill.  With the **in** might imply the deficiency is limited to certain skill only.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - I also see that distinction. "John lacked <thing>" sounds to me like John had none of it, whereas "John was lacking in <thing>" sounds more like he had some, but not as much as he needed / wanted / would be expected to have.

Comment: Would you mind writing the second comment in your answer. Because that specifically addresses the question.

Answer (score 1):

Both your sentences seems fine. Although in place of second one, you could simply say: "The teacher *lacked* communication skills".

From [Oxford Dictionaries:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lacking?q=lacking%20)

> Police presence, which is [lacking](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lacking?q=lacking%20), should act as a deterrent for
>   criminals.

and,

> For someone so [lacking in](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lacking?q=lacking%20) motivation, he has done quite well for
>   himself.

Comment: Thanks Arrowfar. So in your second sentence is word lacking adjective?

Comment: @Murat Yeah it is an 'adjective'

Answer (score 0):

Both are okay. OxfordDictionaries and Dictionary.com talk about it.

Dictionary.com defines *lack in* as [a verb phase](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lack+in) which does not require an object as mentioned in [OxfordDictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/lack) `She lacks in patience` is the example there.

On the other hand, *lack something* is used with object and in your question, you have used it correctly by mentioning *communication skill [sic]*. It's the use of [verb with object](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/lack). `The novel lacks imagination` is the example.