# So, we don't have "lack (n)" in plural form, do we?

Tags: word-usage

In [this dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lack_1?q=lack)

> [uncountable, singular] lack (of something) the state of not having
>   something or not having enough of something
>
> a lack of food/money/skills
>
> The trip was cancelled through lack of (=because there was not enough) interest.
>
> There was no lack of volunteers.
>
> She showed a distinct lack of enthusiasm for the idea of becoming a mother.

So, we don't say "**We have some lacks of skills**" but "**We have a lack of skills**", do we?

**So, "lack (n)" has no plural form but singular one only, is that right?**

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38025/the-usage-of-word-lack

Comment: It _has_ a plural form, but no-one today would understand a speaker who uses it. OED has, from 1652: _The ablest [servant] that any Lady of your lacks and longings ever bestow'd a favour on_

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our%20lacks%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en  But the plural "lacks" is not used in the partitive sense (with **of** + noun).